# how to keep persistent connections to firebase database using superagent package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i am actually following the firebase functions documentation about [optimizing firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking#http_requests_with_a_superagent_package)

i have included the code for reference.

```
    const request = require('superagent');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.function = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    request
        .get('<URL>')
        .end((err, response) => {
            res.status(200).send(`Data: ${response.text}`);
    });
});
```

but as described in the link i wanted to maintain persistent connections to the database and i am trying to use the superagent package but can't figure out about the URL before hand as described in function.

I am new to functions and the simple functions i've done will give me the URL after function deploy completes.

Please can someone tell me how to exactly use this superagent package with firebase functions.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the Firebase documentation is unfortunately incorrect.  However, it's supposed to match the [equivalent Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking#http_requests_with_a_superagent_package) that also shows how to use superagent.  After you convert it to use the Firebase SDK, it'll look something like this:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const https = require('https');
const keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });

exports.function = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    request
        .get('<URL>')
        .agent(keepAliveAgent)
        .end((err, response) => {
            res.status(200).send(`Data: ${response.text}`);
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks @Doug Stevenson, but what about the " .get('<URL>') ", the URL mentioned here what is this, I am not sure what this URL should be.?